# dripping faucets

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I have a delta faucet with ceramic valve bodies in my kitchen. It was dripping and I replaced both hot and cold and it's still dripping but not as bad. My gas hot water tank(watts expansion tank at default 40psi ) is new. What could be making it continue to leak?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Did the dripping start when you replaced the hot water tank? Are you having any problems other than this one dripping faucet? If it's a two-knob faucet, are both dripping?

Comment: After the repacement and I'm pretty sure it's the cold side that's dripping. No other problems.